# Can Less CSS do maths like SASS does?

Tags: css, sass, less

I am new to LESS and was wondering how I convert the following from SASS to LESS?

```
@screen-xs-max: (@screen-sm-min - 1);
```

Does LESS support this out of the box? I'm struggling to find any documentation that tells me one way or the other...

Comment: Like variables and operations? http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**.

The simplest way to find out would just be to try it, and see if it works.

There's a handy website for testing Less:
http://less2css.org/

You could input your above code there, add a rule that uses the variable, and then see if the output matches your expectation.

Also, the documentation does actually specifically tell you that you can do this. The relevant section can be found here:

http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations

Comment: http://lesstester.com/ - it's almost five years outdated version. The official online test tool is http://less2css.org

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks for the tip! I had no idea there was an official tool. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated